# Memory error while generating the openstreet map tiles from generate_tiles.py

Tags: python-2.7, openstreetmap

I am facing weired behavioue of python. when i set the small value of the bound i am able to generate the tiles for small portion .but when i am setting bound value to large number like 60232323.73 i am getting memory error in Generate_tile.py.

Please help on this

Comment: Please provide more details. Show us the exact error message you are receiving, including any relevant parameters etc.

Comment: Here is the error description render_tiles( (6191256.42, 842455.88, 11502754.24, 4218918.81) osm.xml D:\tiles/
 1 16 Bharat )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mapnik\generate_tiles.py", line 222, in <module>
    render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, 1,16,"Bharat")
  File "C:\mapnik\generate_tiles.py", line 159, in render_tiles
    for x in range(int(px0[0]/256.0),int(px1[0]/256.0)+1):
MemoryError

Comment: but i am getting this value from my data base itself when i execute the following query on my DB.              psql -U postgres -d osm -c "SELECT ST_extent(way) FROM osm_line"

Comment: and one  more issue i identified is my table is generating by the name osm_line but while running the generate_image.py it gives me error relation planet_som_line not  defined and after renaming the table all work fine you have any idea on this?

Comment: No, I don't. Please ask a separate question about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`6191256.42, 842455.88, 11502754.24, 4218918.81` is not a valid [bounding box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box). The latitude (2nd and 4th parameter) must be between `-90.0` and `90.0` and the longitude (1st and 3rd parameter) must be between `-180.0` and `180.0`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer scai,it works for me,silly mistake from my side:)